# Redirecting folder to root with rewrite

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm new to Nginx and try to redirect a directory for jpg-files to the root directory.

```
rewrite /(.*(jpg|jpeg))$ /directory/$1 last;
```

The actual solution works, but unfortunately all jpg files in other directories can't be opened any more. Please can anyone help? Many greetings

Comment: As it removes all complexity - why don't you just point at `/directory/foo.jpg`? You should, for clarity, add an example of "unfortunately" you probably just want `[^/]+` in your regex.

Comment: Thanks to the much older and less intelligent planet two with the human DNA, no it must be a redirection. Other answers?

Comment: You mean other than "read the rest of my previous comment" :)?